# .htaccess rewrite /profile.php?username=Something

Tags: .htaccess

I had this code before

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1
```

But that makes the profiles go to **coolsite.com/Something** I want the profile link go to **/profile/Something** instead of **profile.php?username=Something**

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is more to your question then I'm seeing, simply changing your RewriteRule to something like the following should do the trick.

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: It worked. Tho when i use it i suppose it "acts" like a folder. So when i go to it all design on design is gone. just white background and text

Comment: @SigveAleksander All of your resources (images, js, css) should be in directories in your web root. This way you can access them with absolute urls: `/js`, `/css`, `/images`, etc.